# Order of a pole and the Residue

Tags: complex-analysis

I have $\int_{C}\frac{e^{z} - 1}{z^6}$. The contour is irrelevant at the moment.

I initially thought the order of the singularity of $z = 0$ would be $6$, but it turns out is $5$. Because  $$e^z - 1 = z + \frac {z^2}{2} + ...$$so $$\frac{e^z - 1}{z^6} = \frac {1}{z^5} + \frac {1}{2z^4} + ...$$  So it has a singularity of order $5$. What then will my $f(z)$ be? I need to know so I can computing the residue.

Comment: Firstly, the contour does matter. Does it enclose $0$? Secondly, you've already begun to expand the numerator. Why don't you continue to see that the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ is? Finally, what is this function $f(z)$ to which you refer?

Comment: Well, I said it didn't matter since I knew it enclosed the singularity. Why does the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ matter?

Comment: I should take another step back. What is your definition of a residue?

Comment: The $a_{-1}$ coefficient of the Laurent Series representation of $f(z)$. In this exercise, $f(z)$ would be our integrand.

Comment: Ok. So you've answered your own question about what $f(z)$ is. And perhaps you now see that the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z}$ is the residue.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. I expanded $e^z - 1$ at $z=0$ with the Taylor Series. Then I divided that by $z^6$. What I have now is an approximation of $\frac{e^z - 1}{z^6}$. $\frac{1}{z^5} + \frac{1}{2z^4} + ...$ isn't the Laurent Series.

Comment: Residue is the coefficient of $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ where $z_0$ is isolated singular point. Residue of $f (z)$ at $z=0$ is 1/5!.

Answer (score 0):

We want the coefficient of the $z^{-1}$ term in the expansion of $\frac{e^z-1}{z^6}$, so we look for the $z^5$ term in $e^z-1$, since dividing this by $z^6$ will yield the $z^{-1}$ term. Using Taylor series, we see that the $z^5$ term in $e^z-1$ has coefficient $1/120$. This is then the residue.